# Zurb Foundation 6: nested expanded grid with no-padding

Tags: css, html, grid, zurb-foundation

I try create a grid form like this shape with Zurb Foundation 6.

[image]

it has **no-padding**, **width:100% (for all size)** and **responsive**

I try do it this way:

```
<div class="expanded  row" style="background:yellow;">
        <div class="small-10 columns" style="background:grey;">
          <div class="row" style="background:yellow;">
            <div class="small-6 columns" style="background:blue;">6 Nested</div>
            <div class="small-6 columns" style="background:blue;">6 Nested</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 columns" style="background:grey;">
          <div class="row" style="background:yellow;">
            <div class="small-12 columns" style="background:blue;">12 Nested</div>
            <div class="small-12 columns" style="background:blue;">12 Nested</div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

this is the result:

[image]

You can see it is similar to what I want,But nested rows have padding right and left (I marketed them with starts in the shape)

how can I remove that padding (with foundation standard)?

Also I tried `collapse`

EDit:

```
`padding:0`  in `<div class="small-2 columns"` can solve problem but I want to know whats is 'Zurb Foundation' solution?
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) replicating your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The padding come from columns class. For remove this, use collapse.

From foundation:

> The .collapse class lets you remove column gutters (padding).

[source](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#collapse-uncollapse-rows)

Do you have any question?

Answer (score 1):

I solved nested padding problem for expanded rows by adding this:

```
.row.expanded .row {
  @include grid-row-nest($grid-column-gutter);
}
```